# Goldilocks Zone Temperature Range for Habitation

Tags: exoplanet, temperature

Is there a generally accepted Kelvin temperature range for exoplanets habitable zone.  So for example, I can look at for example, http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/toi-2134_b/ and say the planet is in the Goldilocks Temperature zone?  I don't want to know if the planet is in the zone, I want to know how to determine if the planet is in the zone.

305k TO 311.75K (converted from Celsius) seems a little narrow but is that right?
https://body.io/the-goldilocks-zone-too-hot-too-cold-or-just-right-part-i-muscle-thermodynamics/

Or should I be looking at other values as well such as Semi-Major Axis ?

Answer (score 2):

Surface temperatures suitable for liquid surface water for at least part of the year are generally considered necessary for a planet to be considered habitable for liquid water using lifeforms.

At Earth's sea level atmospheric pressure water is liquid between 0 degrees  C, or 32 F, or 273.15 K, and 99.98 degrees C, or 211.96 F, or 373.13 K.

Of course with a different atmospheric pressure the temperature range for liquid surface water will change.

If  you know the inner and outer limits of the Sun's circumstellar habitable zone or Goldilocks zone and also know the luminosity of a star relative to that of the Sun, you can calculate the inner and outer limits of that star's goldilocks zone.

Unfortunately there are several widely different estimates of the inner and outer limits, or both, of the Sun's circumstellar habitable zone.  So unless someone identifies and uses the most accurate estimate of the Sun's Goldilocks zone as the basis for their calculations, they are are likely to be mistaken about the size of another star's goldilocks zone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone#Solar_System_estimates

A star's habitable zone for liquid water using life in general is likely to be larger than it's habitable zone for humans and beings with similar requirement in particular.  Some calculations indicate that The inner and/or outer limits of star's habitable zone can be extended if a planet has some specific atmospheric compositions, which might not be compatible for breathability for humans.